# Select the correct item from drop down menu for dynamic values using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, css

Please see the image below:
[image: Drop down menu items & their identifiers]

I want to use emulate a mouse click to select the option no. 7 "No growth" by JS using the following code:

```
document.querySelector('[id="a5ec764cecf2-6"]').click();
```

But the problem is that this value "a5ec764cecf2-6" **is dynamic and changes with every page refresh**; only the end part '-6' of the a5ec764cecf2-6 remains constant. The part previous to this keeps on changing. Please help me to solve my prblem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('<parentElementSelector>'))[6].click()
```

would it solve your problem ?

Comment: Its not working. Can pattern matching be used here?

Comment: did you replace <parentElementSelector> with a proper selector ?

Comment: What would be the selector name? Will it involve pattern match?

Comment: You should post the html surrounding the element you want to catch. You could also read this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp